# Google Slides Default Paragraph Line Spacing

Tags: formatting, google-slides

Google Slides has seemingly changed default paragraph styles in a recent update. Now, after pressing Enter (i.e. inserting a new paragraph), the last line on the previous paragraph gets extra line spacing. It does not look like that option can be changed in the "Theme Builder" because there is no paragraph in the default slides that can be edited.

I know about `Format` → `Line Spacing`. However, the question is: is there a global option where it does not insert all that extra (wasted) space by default, and I don't have to change it for every paragraph individually?

## The Problem: added paragraph line space

[image]

## Hopes and Dreams

[image]